# Handling multiple fields with one XML tag in C# XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a XML snippet that looks like this:

```
<object>
  <field name="p1">Foo</field>
  <field name="p2">Bar</field>
  <field_list name="p3">
    <field_value>Me</field_value>
    <field_value>Myself</field_value>
    <field_value>I</field_value>
  </field_list>
</object>
```

What I would like to do is represent this in C# as a Dictionary - the keys are the names (p1, p2, p3) and the values are a List of strings - the first two (p1, p2) would have a single element and the third (p3) would have three elements.

This Xml document needs to be de-serialized.  How can I do this and end up with the object desired?

Comment: Dictionary doesn't allow for re-use of the same key (i.e. key "p3" can only show up once), so you'd have to define it as Dictionary<string, string[]> (or some variation of IEnumerable<string>) in order to support your data.  And given that Dictionary isn't natively serializable (as @akton lays out nicely below) I'm not sure it's your best choice.

Comment: A NameValueCollection would allow for duplicate key values, but I think it has similar serialization issues to Dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) class does not serialize `Dictionary` natively. However, there are third party serializers available such as [sharp serializer](http://www.sharpserializer.com/en/index.html) and [one from Peter Welter](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx).

If you want to implement it yourself without additional libraries, implement [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) and provide custom implementations of ReadXml and WriteXml.

See also:

- [Why doesn't XmlSerializer support Dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911514/why-doesnt-xmlserializer-support-dictionary)
- [Deserializing with XmlSerializer List into Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123921/deserializing-with-xmlserializer-list-into-dictionary)
- [Why isn't there an XML-serializable dictionary in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124597/why-isnt-there-an-xml-serializable-dictionary-in-net)